# socket.on listen too much

Tags: reactjs, socket.io, react-hooks

I created a socket in store (`socket.store.ts`)

```
constructor() {
    this.socket = io.connect(process.env.REACT_APP_SOCKET_URI || '3131');
}
```

Using that socket in my component. When user click find button, socket emit one time (checked) to backend, backend emit one time (checked) back to event 'finding'. But `called` printed into console 12 times and even increase rapidly when i re-click find button

```
const socketStore = useContext(SocketStoreContext);
const socket = socketStore.socket;

// THOUGHT: maybe i will try to create socket inside this component
// const socket = io.connect(process.env.REACT_APP_SOCKET_URI);

socket.on('finding', () => {
    console.log('called');
});

const handleFindPartner = () => {
    socket.emit('find', {
      token: user.token,
    });
};
```

But when I create socket inside my component, `called` printed exactly one time. Don't know what going on here, really need some help. Thank you you guys so much!

Comment: `socket.on(...)` is similar to `thing.addEventListener(...)`: you should only define that _once_ otherwise you're just adding more and more listeners for one event, _all of which_ will trigger for that event.

Comment: what do you mean? I  only have once `socket.on('finding', () => {})`

Comment: Maybe you do, maybe you don't: can you show enough code to constitute a [mcve]? Hard to tell what your code actually does in its current form.

Answer (score 0):

Like @Mike said in comment section. I need to prevent `socket.on` from re-rendering by putting it in useEffect

```
const socketStore = useContext(SocketStoreContext);
const socket = socketStore.socket;

// THOUGHT: maybe i will try to create socket inside this component
// const socket = io.connect(process.env.REACT_APP_SOCKET_URI);

React.useEffect(()=>{
   socket.on('finding', () => {
       console.log('called');
   });
},[socket])

const handleFindPartner = () => {
    socket.emit('find', {
      token: user.token,
    });
};
```